# XPath to select all href links that start with something

Tags: python, html, xml, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I'm looking to get some information from this URL:

https://www.bandsintown.com/c/madison-wi?date=2023-04-08T00%3A00%3A00%2C2023-04-09T23%3A00%3A00&date_filter=Choose+Dates&calendarTrigger=false

Using Selenium:

```
find_href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"')
```

Also, I've tried:

```
find_href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'a[starts-with(@href="https://www.bandsintown.com/e")]')
```

Here's an example of a link I would want to get:

https://www.bandsintown.com/e/1027653913-orquesta-salsoul-del-mad-at-the-bur-oak?came_from=253&utm_medium=web&utm_source=city_page&utm_campaign=event

So I want to grab anything with `"www.bandsintown.com/e"`

I'm getting the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e" because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Do I have a syntax error in my XPath statement?

### Update

Tried this:

```
find_href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"]')
```

And I still get the same error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"] because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"]' is not a valid XPath expression.
```

Comment: It's worth noting that when you call `driver.find_element` your context node is the document root. So an XPath of `a` is evaluated relative to that context, and will therefore only return a non-empty set of nodes if the root element of the document is an `a` element, but of course it'll actually be an `html` element. To search for `a` elements anywhere in the document, you should use `//a`. The `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`, so `//a` will take every node which is the document root node or any descendant, and return any child `a` elements which they may have.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your syntax errors, change

```
a[href^="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"
  ^^^^^                                ^
```

to

```
a[@href="https://www.bandsintown.com/e"]
  ^^^^^                                ^
```

---

After correcting your XPath syntax, you found that this wasn't selecting what you wanted.

To select all `a` elements with a `href` attribute that starts with `"https://www.bandsintown.com/e"`, use this XPath:

```
//a[@href[starts-with(.,"https://www.bandsintown.com/e")]]
```

to select all of those `a` element's `href` attributes:

```
//a[@href[starts-with(.,"https://www.bandsintown.com/e")]]/@href
```

(There are 116 such `a` elements at the time of this answer.)

Comment: Shoot, it still can't find the element now.  This should work right? In other words, searching for href that starts with a string: find_href = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'a[starts-with(@href="https://www.bandsintown.com/e")]')

Comment: @DiamondJoe12:  I've updated the answer to show you how to adapt your syntactically-correct XPath to select `a`s with a `href` that starts with a given string.

Comment: A slightly shorter equivalent is `//a/@href[starts-with(., "https://www.bandsintown.com/e")]`

Comment: @ConalTuohy: Yes, good point about the second example, assuming it's the `@href` values and not the `a` elements that are desired.  Thanks.